# FAQ Update: Add "Chrubuntu" to the list of unsupported derivatives

Tags: feature-request, faq-suggestion

Since people are naturally lazy, perhaps we should replace this line in the FAQ:

> - Linux Mint, Backtrack, Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04) and ...

with:

> - Linux Mint, Backtrack, Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04), Chrubuntu, and ...

so that it's there, in case anyone REALLY wants to argue about Chrubuntu not being on topic here.

Is this possible, and if so can we have this done?

Comment: It's possible, yes. Just need a mod (or maybe an employee) to do it.

Comment: I'll see if I can.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to say no to this. We really can't keep listing a distribution EVERY single time. There are so many unsupported distros that it'll be impossible to scale every time someone decides they're right. The on-topic section explicitly mentions only distros listed [on this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives). That should be clear enough it's not supported.

If people have a problem grasping that, let a mod know.

Comment: i agree we can't list it every time, but i wanted to put this out here as a suggestion, however if we start seeing a huge influx of Chrubuntu questions, should we revisit this?

Comment: @thelordoftime I guess we'll cross that bridge when we come to it.

Comment: Revisit? Sure. However, given no one really reads the FAQ to begin with, having it in there really won't help much.

Comment: And even after reading the FAQ, there are arguments as to its interpretation :)