# How is this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, scope, derivatives

I posted a question about the crouton tool for creating an ubuntu environment in chrome os, but it was put on hold as off-topic. The question is this:

> I attempted several times to use the crouton tool to have Ubuntu 12.04 with the unity desktop on my Google ChromeBook. Every time I tried it, it would work the first time after being set up. However, when I shut the Ubuntu machine down and went back to Chrome OS, then went back in, the desktop background would load, but the toolbar on the side of the screen and the bar at the top would not appear.
>
> I would end up with it sitting there, just the cursor on the standard Ubuntu desktop background. I got around this by using the gnome desktop, but I much prefer Unity and would like to be able to use it on my new ChromeBook.
>
> Does anyone know why this happened or if there is some way for me to avoid it or fix it?

I looked around and found another question about crouton, that has been around for two years and has an answer. It is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/348383/chromebook-crouton-ram-limit

In fact, there are several:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/450856/chromebook-crouton-installation-continually-failing
- [Are there alternative repositories to ports.ubuntu.com for ARM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428698/chromebook-with-crouton-alternative-repository-to-ports-ubuntu-com)
- [Crouton install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564921/crouton-install)
- [No Sound in ARM HP Chromebook Ubuntu 14.04 with Crouton](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470876/no-sound-in-arm-hp-chromebook-ubuntu-14-04-with-crouton)

My question is this. Why was my question put on hold as off-topic, when all of these other questions were allowed to go on for years and even have answers?
And if my question was put on hold for a different reason, what was it?

Comment: related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8025/how-to-resolve-conflicting-information-about-chrubuntu-policy-status < although about "crubuntu". not "crouton" crouton might be further from stock ubuntu

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6690/faq-update-add-chrubuntu-to-the-list-of-unsupported-derivatives/6694#6694

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/24/what-ubuntu-versions-are-covered

Comment: plus your question was specifically about the installation and hardware side, so unless people "own" that same chromebook they can't help...

Comment: Thanks for notifying us. I'll be voting to close these questions as off-topic as well.

Comment: I would dump anything crouton in unix and linux SE.

Comment: There is a simple fact about crouton. IT IS UBUNTU!

Comment: And what do you mean by "own"?

Comment: @Serg - consider posting that as an answer. Along those lines, questions on crouton have become quite common, perhaps add it to the list here - http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Posted. Shall i delete the comment ?

Comment: @Serg - up to you. Comments tend to get lost and I did not see your the first time I looked (sorry )

Comment: @XamuelDvorak purchace, buy, aquire, personally own. I can't instruct on installing on that type of chromebook without owning one, as the install and kernel are altered to a  point that normal installation procedures are not the same

Comment: @Mateo But why the quotes?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes ,  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crouton is just another boot-loader¹, so once Crouton got Ubuntu up-and-running, it's just plain old Ubuntu (without grub) and **questions about Ubuntu are on-topic!**

#### However, questions *about the Crouton boot process itself* are off-topic!

## Clear and simple...  :-)

¹<sub>Technically, it's not a boot loader: it's a [chroot](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Autostart-crouton-chroot-at-ChromeOS-startup), but 90% of users who see this answer won't know what a chroot is so...</sub>

Comment: Doesn't crouton run Ubuntu in a chroot? https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/blob/0cac566a7fe7da6052682762860176d2c1420080/README.md#whats-a-chroot

Comment: @mchid: Yes...  So what are you trying to say?

Comment: It's just that a chroot is a bit different than a boot loader and I think it depends on the host machine kernel for some stuff. A chroot environment may also encounter permission issues within certain parts of the filesystem depending on how it is implemented.

Comment: @mchid: *Sigh*  Happy now?  **;-)**

Answer (score 3):

Askubuntu is more for officially supported versions, such as unity ubuntu, lubuntu, xubuntu, gnome ubuntu, kubuntu , and edubuntu. Crouton isn't officially supported , hence off-topic. Same with Linux Mint - even if under the hood it's all one big debian family, it's still different distribution

Comment: Along those lines, questions on crouton have become quite common, perhaps add it to the list here - http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Exactly. At least allow questions about the Ubuntu side of it, since it's really just Ubuntu within a Chrome OS file system.