# Clarification on GRUB's on-topic-ness

Tags: discussion, scope, grub

By definition questions that are on topic are these:

> Using and administering official Ubuntu flavors including: Edubuntu,
>   Ubuntu GNOME, Kubuntu, Ubuntu Kylin, Lubuntu, Mythbuntu, Ubuntu
>   Studio, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Touch, and Ubuntu "Snappy" Core.
>
> Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.
>
> Development on Ubuntu.  Services provided by Ubuntu and Canonical. 
>   Any question not mentioned below or here are great!

Where does GRUB fit in under these requirements ? Technically it's not `Running . . . on Ubuntu` it loads before the OS itself. In one of [Oli's answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14083/295286), he mentions :

> [Questions] how it's installed (and how it boots) are not Ubuntu proper and are
>   off-topic.

And yet, we have GRUB tags and tons of questions related to those. My understanding is that since GRUB comes with Ubuntu by default, it is therefore on topic here. It's also something that can be configured/controlled from Ubuntu. Config files for GRUB are also part of the root filesystem , particularly those in `/etc`.

**NOTE**: I'm seeking clarification that draws on at least semi official sources and/or previous meta posts, preferably by our current moderators. In other words, **I don't want  opinions but facts here**

Comment: Technically it is under "using and administering". GRUB options do  play a role in administering Ubuntu, and using it alongside other OSes.

Comment: @muru OK , what else there is ? Has it been officially mentioned by mods ?

Comment: Whatever comes under a reasonable meaning of "using" and "administering". I'd say nobody is going to enumerate all the possibilities for you.

Comment: @muru   I don't want all possibilities. I want clear definition, and in case of GRUB that definition is very vague

Comment: Clear definition of "using" and "administering"? You want a mod to point to X dictionary and say "This is the official meaning of these words for Ask Ubuntu"?

Comment: Take, for example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/819856/unable-to-replace-grub-bootloader-with-windows-10-bootloader-from-windows-10-ins, which is off-topic for me, since Ubuntu is long gone and the problem is between Kali and Windows. But that doesn't mean GRUB is always off-topic for me.

Comment: @Muru  I know what using and administering means.  It's very arguable that even though GRUB comes with Ubuntu installation , it's not under "Running 3rd party apps on Ubuntu" , since it shows up way before actual OS runs. This is exactly same discussion i had with other users in chat today. Don't get me wrong, I believe it's perfectly on topic. But for the sake of others, I want to know where it stands.

Comment: Most GRUB configuration is done by running third party apps on Ubuntu, though, even if GRUB itself isn't. And I'd rather these "others" raise this question if and when it actually becomes a problem.

Comment: @muru  Hmmm, that's an interesting point there . . . As for "other" users , what difference it makes if I ask this sooner or they later ? Also, not a problem, it's a person seeking clarification - that's all.

Comment: Exactly: what difference does it make? So, why ask if there isn't a problem? Is there a flood of GRUB questions without any Ubuntu involvement?

Comment: @muru there were a few here and there :)

Comment: @Serg btw, if it wasn't for a couple of GRUB questions/solutions here, I wouldn't have been able to use Ubuntu on my laptop. *I know I could have found my answers elsewhere, but I'd expect the solution to run Ubuntu on my machine, to be on an Ubuntu site*

Comment: @Dan well, that's the whole point of my question - to ensure these questions 100% belong here and there's no confusion between new and existing users. As well as some users who have been here a while

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Erm...

> In one of [Oli's answers](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14083/295286), he mentions :
>
> > [Questions] how it's installed (and how it boots) are not Ubuntu proper and are off-topic.

That's firmly within the context of Crouton, which is a hacked-together way to shim Ubuntu onto a Chromebook.

Grub in the context of Ubuntu is on topic. It's an officially supported application that couldn't be any more a part of Ubuntu if it wanted to be. Why would we ever consider that off-topic?

Comment: OK, and just one more question . . .which category it's supposed to belong to ? "Use and administration" as muru suggests or "3rd party apps" ?

Comment: Using Ubuntu. It's very hard to use Ubuntu (on a traditional computer) without it.

Comment: @Serg the way I see it is that it's a piece of software which you *install* in Ubuntu. True, strictly speaking, it doesn't actually run on Ubuntu but as long as it's something you can `apt-get install` it seems kinda hard to argue it's off topic.

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek remark: you can pretty easily use Ubuntu with BURG or rEFInd as well. :P